# If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ with $\vert A \vert = \infty,$ does $\exists p\in\mathbb{P}_{\geq 3}$ such that $\vert\{a\pmod p:a\in A\}\vert=p$ or $p-1?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of prime numbers.

My original question was going to be this:

> If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ with $\ \vert A \vert = \infty,\ $ does $\ \exists\ p\in\mathbb{P} $ such
> that $\ \displaystyle \{ a \pmod p: a\in A \}
>  = [p]:= \{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}\ ?$

But then I realised that $ A= \{ 2^k: k\in\mathbb{N} \}$ is a counter-example, because no such $p\in\mathbb{P}$ exists with the desired property. This is because for $p=2,$ no member of $A$ is $\equiv 1 \pmod 2.$ And for $p\geq 3,\ $ no member of $A$ is $\equiv 0 \pmod p$ because members of $A$ do not contain multiples of primes other than $2.\ $

With similar reasoning, we see that for any prime $p,\ A= \{ p^k: k\in\mathbb{N} \}$ is a counter-example.

The following question naturally arises:

> If $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ with $\ \vert A \vert = \infty.\ $ Does $\exists\ p\in\mathbb{P}_{\geq 3}\ $ such
> that $\ \displaystyle \vert\ \{ a \pmod p: a\in A \}\ \vert = p\ $ or $\ p-1\ ?$

Or much stronger:

> For every $M\in\mathbb{N},\ $ does $\exists\ p\in\mathbb{P}_{\geq M}\ $ such
> that $\ \displaystyle \vert\ \{ a \pmod p: a\in A \}\ \vert = p\ $ or $\ p-1\ ?$

Elementary number theory theorems like Chinese Remainder Theorem come to mind, as does the pigeonhole principle, but I just don't see how to use these yet to answer the new question. Maybe there is a counter-example, but I do not currently see how to construct it.

Comment: Is this true?  I'd have thought some sequence of primorials would violate it.  Let $a_n$ be the product of the first $10^{100n}$ primes , something like that.  Or something self-referential, like letting $a_n$ equal $a_{n-1}$ times the product of all the primes which are "getting close " to your condition (clearly a finite list, however you define "getting close").

Comment: I think a better question is to restrict the set $A$ to those such that $\sum \frac 1{a_n}$ diverges, something like that.  Obviously, my primorial examples (and that of @ArturoMagidin) grossly fail that.   Not sure about my self-referential one, though I expect it grows too fast as well.

Comment: @lulu Another natural follow-up question would be with sets with positive natural upper density (maybe before looking at "large" subsets of $ \mathbb{N}.$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ be the primes in ascending order, starting with $p_1=3$ (so $p_2=5$, $p_3=7$, etc).

Let
$$\begin{align*}
a_0 &=1\\
a_1 &= 1+p_1\\
a_2 &= 1+p_1p_2\\
&\vdots\\
a_k &= 1+p_1p_2\cdots p_k\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$
and let $A=\{a_0,a_1,\ldots\}$. Let $p\geq 3$ be a prime, say $p=p_n$. For all $m\geq n$ we have $a_m = 1+p_1\cdots p_m \equiv 1\pmod{p_n}$. Thus, the set $\{a\bmod p_n\mid a\in A\}$ has at most $n$ distinct elements (namely, $a_0\bmod p_n,\ldots,a_{n-1}\bmod p_n$). Because $p_n\geq n+2$ holds for all $n$, it follows $p_n-1\geq n+1 \gt n$, so that $|\{a\bmod p_n\mid a\in A\}|\leq n \lt p_n-1$.

Comment: Why add $1$?  Why not just take the primorials?  Works either way, of course, I'm just curious.

Comment: @lulu: Because I wanted to avoid $0$ for absolutely no good reason; you could add any fixed integer, of course, and get the same conclusion.

Comment: Absolutely.  Got it.